# How to move files from one folder to another on databricks

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I am trying to move the file from one folder to another folder using databricks python notebook.
My source is azure data lake gen 1.

Suppose, my file is present adl://testdatalakegen12021.azuredatalakestore.net/source/test.csv
and I am trying to move the file from adl://testdatalakegen12021.azuredatalakestore.net/demo/test.csv to adl://testdatalakegen12021.azuredatalakestore.net/destination/movedtest.csv

I tried various logic but not none of my code is working fine.

```
# Move a file by renaming it's path
import os
import shutil
os.rename('adl://testdatalakegen12021.azuredatalakestore.net/demo/test.csv', 'adl://testdatalakegen12021.azuredatalakestore.net/demo/renamedtest.csv')

# Move a file from the directory d1 to d2
shutil.move('adl://testdatalakegen12021.azuredatalakestore.net/demo/test.csv', 'adl://testdatalakegen12021.azuredatalakestore.net/destination/renamedtest.csv')
```

Please, let me know If I am using correct logic as I am executing this on databricks, not in my local.

Answer (score 3):

To move a file in databricks notebook, you can use [dbutils](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html) as follow:

```py
dbutils.fs.mv('adl://testdatalakegen12021.azuredatalakestore.net/demo/test.csv', 'adl://testdatalakegen12021.azuredatalakestore.net/destination/renamedtest.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are the steps to move files from one folder to another on databricks:

**Mount the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 to the databricks workspace:**

```
configs = {"<prefix>.oauth2.access.token.provider.type": "ClientCredential",
           "<prefix>.oauth2.client.id": "<application-id>",
           "<prefix>.oauth2.credential": dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name-for-service-credential>"),
           "<prefix>.oauth2.refresh.url": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token"}

# Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point.
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "adl://<storage-resource>.azuredatalakestore.net/<directory-name>",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

[image]

**Reference:** [Mount Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 resource using a service principal and OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake#--mount-azure-data-lake-storage-gen1-resource-using-a-service-principal-and-oauth-20)

**Moving file using `%fs` command**

```
%fs mv dbfs:/mnt/adlsgen1/test/mapreduce.txt dbfs:/mnt/adlsgen1/test1/mapreduce.txt
```

[image]

**Moving file using `dbutils` command:**

```
dbutils.fs.mv('dbfs:/mnt/adlsgen1/test/data.csv', 'dbfs:/mnt/adlsgen1/test1/dataone.csv')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am getting below error while performing same steps
py4j.security.Py4JSecurityException: Constructor public com.databricks.backend.daemon.dbutils.DBUtilsCore(org.apache.spark.SparkContext,org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext) is not whitelisted.

Answer (score 0):

you may want to also move/or copy the file without their subdirectories

```
import os

source_dir = "/mnt/yourplateform/source"
dest_dir= "/mnt/yourplateform/destination//"

list_of_files=[]
fs = spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
path_exists = fs.exists(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(source_dir))
if path_exists == True:
  file_list = fs.listFiles(spark._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(source_dir), True)
  while file_list.hasNext():
    file = file_list.next()
    list_of_files.append(str(file.getPath()))

for file in list_of_files:
  dbutils.fs.mv(file, os.path.join(dest_dir, os.path.basename(file)), recurse=True)
```